# Why i keep getting 'Request' object has no attribute 'file' in Flask while i'm gonna proccess upload images?

Tags: python, flask

so i'm gonna make a website about image classification with user input upload image and and the image will be proccessed in different python file, unfortunately i stuck with this problem over a week

```
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'file'
```

this is the full code of Flask
**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
from Testing import predict

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config["ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS"] = ["JPEG", "JPG", "PNG", "GIF"]
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'uploads'

def allowed_image(filename):

    if not "." in filename:
        return False

    ext = filename.rsplit(".", 1)[1]

    if ext.upper() in app.config["ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS"]:
        return True
    else:
        return False


@app.route('/predict_image/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def render_message():
    # Loading CNN model
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.file['image_retina']
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return render_template('upload.html')

        if file.filename == '':
            return render_template('upload.html')

        if file and allowed_image(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],  filename))

    predict()
    return render_template('upload.html')
```

and this is the code where the image will be proccessed
**Testing.py**

```
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img, img_to_array
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
import time

start = time.time()

# Define Path

test_path = 'data/test_image'




# Define image parameters
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

# Prediction Function


def predict():
    model_path = './models/model.h5'
    model_weights_path = './models/weights.h5'
    model = load_model(model_path)
    model.load_weights(model_weights_path)
    x = load_img(test_path, target_size=(img_width, img_height))
    x = img_to_array(x)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    array = model.predict(x)
    result = array[0]
    # print(result)
    answer = np.argmax(result)

     if answer == 0:
         print("Predicted: Drusen")
     elif answer == 1:
         print("Predicted: Normal")

    return answer


# Calculate execution time
end = time.time()
dur = end-start

if dur < 60:
    print("Execution Time:", dur, "seconds")
elif dur > 60 and dur < 3600:
    dur = dur/60
    print("Execution Time:", dur, "minutes")
else:
    dur = dur/(60*60)
    print("Execution Time:", dur, "hours")
```

**upload.html**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload Gambar</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Upload an Image</h1><br>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="image_retina" name="image_retina">
        <label for="image_retina">Select image...</label><br>

        <button type="submit">Upload</button><br>
        <!-- <a href="/predict_image">bercanda anda</a> -->
    </form>

    {% if message %}
    <p>{{message}}</p><br>


    {% if data.shape[0] > 0 %}

    <!-- {{ data.reset_index(drop = True).to_html(classes="table table-striped") | safe}} -->

    {% endif %}

    <p><img src="{{image_retina}}" style='width:500px' /><br>

        {% endif %}
</body>

</html>
```

thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Should be `request.files` according to the API docs

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.files

Comment: oh so i should use `request.files` instead of `request.file`?

Comment: Yes.  The error message you received indicates there is no such thing as request.file; thus you're probably looking for request.files.  It's always a good idea to check the api documentation of a particular library when using it.